# How to make date format of first date same with the other date

Tags: simpledateformat, date-formatting

I was trying to convert date format. for example I have two kinds of format:

Format1 `Tue, 31 Jan 2017 07:41:06 GMT`

Format2 `2017-01-31T07:41:06.7366667`

Is there any way to convert Format1 same with Format2 or vice versa? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As usual, you need two formatters. One for parsing a string and another one for printing the result of first formatter. However, if you want to work with outdated `SimpleDateFormat`-class and `java.util.Date` then please understand that you will loose the microseconds of your second example (limited to millisecond precision).

Comment: it's ok to loose the microseconds as the first format has no microseconds. Thankyou very much. Is there any solution now?

Answer (score 0):

Use two separate formatters for input and output:

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormatter =
  new SimpleDateFormat("E, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter =
  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
outputFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String converted = 
  outputFormatter.format(
    inputFormatter.parse("Tue, 31 Jan 2017 07:41:06 GMT"));
System.out.println(converted);
// output: 2017-01-31T07:41:06.000
```

A similar approach can be achieved in Java-8 with the new class `DateTimeFormatter`.